# How to list label value for checkboxes in ACF (advanced custom fields)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a list of checkboxes (around 100+) and want to loop through to get the 'label' value without having to do the following 100+ items.

```
<p>Colors: <?php the_field('colors'); ?></p>
```

The checkbox fields are not set up as repeaters or group (see screenshot).

[image]

The code below works for ACF Version 4.4.12 but is not working for ACF Pro 5.6.10.

```
<?php
$groupID = '2893';  // Package Inclusions
$package_inclusions1 = apply_filters('acf/field_group/get_fields', 
array(), $groupID);

foreach($package_inclusions1 as $k=>$v) {
  $data = get_field($v['name']);
  if($data[0] == 'Yes') {
    echo '<li class="package-inclusion">' . $v['label'] . '</li>';
  }
}
?>
```

Apparently, [The filter has been removed in ACF5 and was not replaced.](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/filter-acffield_groupget_fields-missing-in-acf-pro/)

Any solution to this? I've looked enough, couldn't find a solution.

**Edit [solution]:** 24 July 2018

Asked this question to ACF Support and here's the solution they provided that works.

"
The acf/field_group/get_fields filter was removed in the Pro version and in its place the acf_get_fields() function was introduced. You can use this function like so:

$fields = acf_get_fields($group_id); "

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to get list of fields for specific post/page

```
$fields = get_field_objects($post_id, [$format_value], [$load_value]);
```

or you want to get all fields and loop through them to get fields value and label use below code :

-> For testing use below code and check what `var_dump` prints value

```
$fields = get_field_objects();
var_dump($fields);
```

-> For Loop through all fields use below code after checking var_dump if its printing perfect value as you want.

```
$fields = get_field_objects();

if ($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field) {
       $data = get_field($field_name);

       if ($data[0] == 'Yes') {
           echo '<li class="package-inclusion">' . $field['label'] . '</li>';
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the value when you print_r $fields, but still, how do I print
`code`
        <li>China basin and dual flush toilets </li>
        <li>Chrome bathroom accessories</li>
        <li> and so on... </li>

Comment: I also coded foreach loop to print that label and its value

Comment: use foreach as you need

Comment: This is what I got, it still doesn't output anything.

`code`
$fields = get_field_objects();


if ($fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $k => $v) {
        $data = get_field($v['name']);
        if ($data[0] == 'Yes') {
            echo '<li class="package-inclusion">' . $field['label'] . '</li>';
        }
   }
}


Here's the var_dump output -> https://pastebin.com/3EKzmVpV

Comment: use this to get data : $data = get_field($k['name']); and to print label use $v['label'] as you are now using loop

Comment: To get field use `$data = get_field($k['name']);` and to print label use `'<li class="package-inclusion">' . $v['label'] . '</li>`

Comment: Still no output. I must mention that there are other fields (all checkboxes) as well for the post (screenshot->https://imgur.com/a/X7uf9sk).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176059/discussion-between-raju-eww-and-sunil-patel).